# Developing for an FPGA using Impulse C

Tags: fpga, hdl

I am considering using [Impulse C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_C) to write C code that will compile down to HDL for my FPGA. I'm curious as to what experiences people have had with Impulse C, to better understand the advantages and disadvantages, and in what cases it makes the most sense to use Impulse C as opposed to raw Verilog or VHDL.

In the pros I expect:

1. Faster development time
2. Cross platform FPGA programming
3. Possibility for writing very complex algorithms take will run in an FPGA

In the cons I expect:

1. Added layer of complexity with the Impulse C framework
2. License fees for using Impulse C
3. Less control over the behaviour of the FPGA
4. Longer compilation cycles

Are these assumptions correct?

I also have specific questions:

1. Does using Impulse C for one part of the project impose using Impulse C for the whole project?
2. Is using Impulse C more or less bug prone than using an HDL?

Comment: Not a full answer for you but usually with a C to RTL approach you won't end up with something that runs as fast, or makes as efficient use of space/resources as if you did it in raw verilog.  However depending on what you're doing, like say porting an algorithm from C, then your dev time will likely be faster.

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy: That's an interesting point. Would be nice to have the speed and space loss quantified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have c code already for the function?  If so it may make some sense...

To answer your specific questions (disclaimer - I haven't used Impulse C, but I have ["read-the-book"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131543180))

You don't have to use impulse for the whole project, it spits out a netlist that you can use as a block within a larger system.

"more or less bug-prone" is a tricky one.  I'd expect it to be easier to test in C than VHDL, so good coverage should be easier to get too.

---

Here's another thought:

For a complex function most of your time is spent writing verification code, so choose a language which makes *that* easy and then interface it to your low-level synthesisable code.

One option for this is MyHDL - you still write the FPGA part at the "behavioural RTL" level, but your testing can take advantage of the whole Python infrastructure.  So:

- You get test management for free - just use one of the existing test frameworks
- You have a random library already for generating test data
- If you are creating an implementation of a standard algorithm (eg SHA) you can generate the expected answers for your random input data using (assumed-)good library code, rather than figuring it out yourself (possibly on paper)
- If you want to use images or audio as input data, you can just call the libraries to do it.
- Dealing with Ethernet packets? there's a library for creating those too
- ... etc!

Using C as your input language, tends to mean then using C (or C++) as your testing language - similar benefits can be had, but they are not "just there" you have to go installing and managing various libraries.

Answer (score 0):

All the C-to-RTL tools I have used tend to build mini-CPUs for each compilation unit. Each sequential operation in the C code maps to sequential states in the generated state machine that are iterated through serially, which is generally a waste of area and time. Now it might be that your FPGA is just so damn big, and your throughput constraints so loose that this is satisfactory, even on a grand scale. But at some point your design might not fit the device, and you'll have piles of coupled sequential processes rather than a true data flow based pipeline to optimise.

If you design for FPGAs starting from a software engineering background, then you perhaps don't appreciate (yet) what a true hardware engineer can make an FPGA do so concisely and at such blisteringly high throughput. They don't generally use C-to-gates to achieve this.

Of course there people who hold the opposite view, and the topic is getting some attention over at [DeepChip: 'We have 46 active, profitable C-to-Silicon projects'](http://www.deepchip.com/items/0512-01.html) recently for being used in commercial design starts.

In terms of "bug prone" they are probably equivalent. It's probably less easy to use waveform viewers to debug C-to-gates output as the register names and functions become obfuscated. Although if the tooling works you shouldn't need to work at this level.